# Compare 2 values from same doc in mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to compare 2 values in same doc `id`

For example

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f180441ad1cd40008dc6a5a"),
    "fcount" : 5,
    "key" : "27b6e581-796c-4f3a-882b-0e0c2a0a8a64",
    "student_id" : "5f0ffbcdd67d70c1a3b143aa",
    "__v" : 0,
    "dcount" : 5
}
```

I have this doc, Now If I want to check `fcount` and `dcount` is same then return `true`. OR `false`
How can I do this with mongoose query?

update:

```
const result = await execute_reports_model.find({ _id: _id}).lean().cursor({batchSize: 10}).eachAsync(async ({fcount, dcount}) => {
                if (fcount === dcount) {
                    // true Logic
                } else  {
                   // false logic
                }
             }, { parallel: 10})
```

So here I will be passing the ID in find. and then compare values that I found from that ID. values are `fcount` and `dcount`

Comment: Could clarify the problem, you want to check every document in the collection or just one (certain) by `find` query?

Comment: Just one at a time

Comment: then you might wanna check my answer

Comment: Yes, so what's the problem then? You already have two different answers, one via `.find`, another via `aggregation`. Both of them will handles your problem, as you described it, so which one you choose? If both are fine, then don't forget to upvote them.

Comment: I have posted an answer. I have assumed the document for the given id exists (and the query compares two fields). _Question_: In case the provided `id` doesn't exist, then what should be the result? `false` _or_ no result at all?

Answer (score 1):

Using Mongoose's [Model.aggregate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.aggregate) you can compare a document's two fields and return a `boolean`:

```
const result = await model.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: id } },
    { $project: { _id: 0, isMatch: { $eq: [ "$fcount", "$dcount" ] } } }
])
```

`result` value: `{ "isMatch" : true }`

Answer (score 0):

This precursor code will help you to solve your problem. It will allow you to find the necessary documents and then deal with all `true` and `false` cases.

`{batchSize: 10}` and `{parallel:10}` will help you to do your task at parallel. You could easily modify them.

Don't forget to add `callback` or handle all cases somehow, as you need it to.

```
await collection_name.find({ your_query: here}).lean().cursor({batchSize: 10}).eachAsync(async ({fcount, dcount}) => {
   if (fcount === dcount) {
       //true case
   } else  {
       //false case
   }
}, { parallel: 10})
```

Comment: here when you say `your_query` then what you you mean? I want to search by Id and then compare 2 values as mentioned in above question.

Comment: I mean that there you should place your search criteria `query`, if you want to find by `id` then it should be `your_collection_name.find({_id: value})`